# Getting a non-free firmware error related to “Realtek RTL8111D-2/RTL8168D-2” firmware when installing Kali Linux

Tags: installation, kali-linux, firmware

I first had the issue with Kali 2020 so I switched to the installer. Same thing. I would get this error message related to `RTL_NIC/rtl8168d-2.fw` (Realtek RTL8111D-2/RTL8168D-2):

> “Some of your hardware needs non-free firmware files to operate. The firmware can be loaded from removable media, such as a USB stick or floppy.   The missing files are : RTL_NIC/rtl8168d-2.fw. If you have such media insert it, etc.”

I went to the Debian site and downloaded the files. Didn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

If you go look at your download or installation files contents on Kali Linux, you will see the folder is empty.

But, if you open the `pool` folder, then open the `non-free` folder, you'll see a bunch of folders that are just letters.

Open folder `f` and then you'll see the `firmware-nonfree` folder.

Copy the entire contents of that folder to the original "Firmware" folder that you see when you open the download, ISO, or whatever the file is.

Paste all the content and replace it.

Then re-install it and you’re good. Hope that helped.